# how to add a custom button at the center of navigation bar in Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

In my iOS application, I want to add a custom button at the center of the navigation bar (that the user will be able to swipe left-right to change active topic).

[image]

When I searched the web, found that images and title text can be located at the center, the other buttons such back, done, etc. are located at the corners.
Thank you

Comment: you can do anything if you want to write it, however I wonder whether coming up with your own behaviour for a standard component might confuse your end users??

Comment: honestly, I would like to use this feature in some other projects as well, it looks like good and very practical for some quick actions. for example when he/she swipes left, "homeworks" switches to "scores" and vice versa. But now, I could not add a button in center of navigation bar, it allows only left or right.